# Ajax/jQuery POST

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm constructing a form where a user can choose something from a dropdown box, then a different form is loaded depending on their selection.

For example if they chose "car" it would load a form for buying a car. However if they chose "dog" it would ask type of dog, etc etc.

I'm having trouble understanding the format in which data is passed to a page. For example, if I have a script in a file called "formLoader.php" that uses a variable name "$selection" to query the database and return the parsed form, how does passing code like the snippet below tell the file to set the value of "$selection" to 'car' for example?

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("formLoader.php",
  {
    selector:"car"
  }
  });
});
```

In other words, when you pass data, how do you assign that data to a variable in a php file?

Thanks

Comment: Via `$_POST['selector'];` -- a basic tutorial in `ajax` and form submission would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks :) I've been reading lots and lots of ajax tutorials but some seem to skip over concepts whereby the writer assumes I'd have that understanding, whereby I don't -- I didn't realize it was passed in a POST array but that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Artical Refer to : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254799/ajax-multiple-drop-downs

Comment: When you are not sure about jquery API, check jquery official API first, e.g. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting data via a form a la:

```
<form action="something.php" method="POST"> or
<form action="something.php" method="GET">
```

or via an AJAX call such as

```
 $.post("something.php", { }); or
 $.get("something.php",{});
```

the data passed in is available in PHP via the `$_POST` and `$_GET` superglobals, respectively (it is also stored in `$HTTP_POST_VARS`, but that's not a superglobal and is deprecated). So in your example, you'd have the following:

formLoader.php

```
$selected = $_POST['selector'];
// do something with the the variable
// echo a result, using json_encode is recommended
```

Now, note that `$.post()` accepts a callback function that runs, accepting whatever your php script dumps out.  (Easy reference: http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/ajax_post.asp )

I also recommend you checkout the jquery documentation for $.post ( http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ ) as well as the PHP documentation for handling form input ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php )

Answer (score 1):

Im didn't clear understand what you are thinking but base on my understanding this is my answer:

suppose this is your ajax.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("formLoader.php",
  {
    'selector':'car'
  }
  });
});
```

In your formLoader.php.

```
$selection = $_POST['selector'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this

```
$("button").click(function(){

$.post("formLoader.php", { selector:"car" },
   function(data) {
            alert(data);
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at both documentations: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php)

You can post the data like this:

```
$.post( "test.php", {
    name: "John", time: "2pm" 
});
```

then, using the PHP reference, you use it like this in server-side (php file that received the POST request):

```
<?php
$myname = $_POST['name']
?>
```

the result will be in yout variable called `$myname`.

Comment: Wonderful answer, sorry it was such a basic question, you answered it perfectly!